# SimpleDateFormat.format(currentDate) does not change currentDate variable

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

when i make something like this in my servlet im still getting date format like `Sun Jun 07 00:59:46 CEST 2020` but i want to make it like `2020.06.07`

**Code in my servlet :**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date currentDate = new Date();
sdfo.format(currentDate);
request.setAttribute("currentDate", currentDate);
```

**And my jsp file :**

`Current date: <c:out value="${currentDate}"/>`

What i should change here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the `currentDate` instead of the formatted date string into `request`.

Replace

```
sdfo.format(currentDate);
request.setAttribute("currentDate", currentDate);
```

with

```
String today = sdfo.format(currentDate);
request.setAttribute("currentDate", today);
```

I also recommend you use [java.time.LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)) instead of using the outdated `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` as shown below:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
String today = currentDate.format(formatter);
request.setAttribute("currentDate", today);
```

Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to learn more about the modern date/time API.

Comment: Alright it's working good but date now is `String` and i want to keep it still like `Date` because i want to compare dates. Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to set it as `Date`, you will have to format it into the JSP.